# How to reload jQuery Masonry, when deleting items with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-masonry

UPDATE:

Here is my CSS:

```
 #masonry-container {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
   width: 50%;
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

---

I'm using Rails 4, Bootstrap and the [Masonry-Rails gem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLOYs.png). I have the following code working for jQuery Masonry to arrange my divs, in assets/javascipts/application.js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#masonry-container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    isFitWidth: true
  });
});

var masonryUpdate = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#masonry-container').masonry();
    }, 200);
}

$(document).on('click', masonryUpdate);
$(document).ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate);
```

It works otherwise, but when I try to delete an item with AJAX, Masonry doesn't update. Here is my view/projects/destroy.js:

```
$('.deleting').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).closest('.poista').fadeOut();
});
```

How could I force Masonry to reload, after the code example above? For some reason .ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate) is not triggered?

It reloads if I do a page refresh, but that takes away the point of using AJAX with the destroy action...

So to explain this further, first my site looks like this:

[image: two columns of divs]

But when I delete a div, Masonry doesn't reload; it ends up looking like this, with an empty space on where the div used to be:

[image: empty space where the div used to be]

How could I reload Masonry after the AJAX destroy action?

Comment: You have to award it manually. Bro please clicked on the +50 near my answer, please :) .To award the bounty manually, click on the +50 (or whatever bounty amount was allocated) button on the left side of the answer you want to award

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.deleting').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    $ele = $(this).closest('.poista');
    $ele.fadeOut(200, function(){
          $("#masonry-container").masonry( 'remove', $ele ).masonry();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work. There is an empty space, where the div used to be...

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Or can you please provde a Live link to your site.

Comment: Why i didnt got the bounties :( .

Comment: That's weird, they did leave from me, and I accepted your answer as correct.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to destroy the Masonry just reinitialize it after the ajax action and reload items using:

```
$container.masonry('reloadItems');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I was looking through [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495814/ajaxcomplete-is-not-triggered-after-deleting-item-with-ajax) of yours and I think I came up with a better solution. Your problem may actually be with the line below.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate);
```

As `ajaxComplete` calls a set handler function with specific arguments [show here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) Your best bet would be to use an anonymous function to call masonryUpdate.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  masonryUpdate();
};
```

This means you won't have to have a `$('.deleting').bind` function to handle deletes.

**Old**

You can actually just call masonry after you have faded an item out

```
$('.deleting').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
  $(this).closest('.poista').fadeOut();
  $('#masonry-container').masonry();
});
```