# .ajaxComplete is not triggered after deleting item with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Rails 4, Bootstrap and Masonry. I have the following code working for jQuery Masonry to arrange my divs, in application.js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#pins').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    isFitWidth: true
  });
});

var masonryUpdate = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#pins').masonry();
    }, 200);
}

$(document).on('click', masonryUpdate);
$(document).ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate);
```

It works otherwise, but when I try to delete an item with AJAX, Masonry doesn't update. Here is my destroy.js:

```
$('.deleting').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).closest('.poista').fadeOut();
});
```

How could I force Masonry to reload, after the code example above? For some reason .ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate) is not triggered?

Comment: Where is the code doing AJAX requests?

Comment: I have the code for  Masonry in assets/javascripts/application.js and the delete call in views/projects/destroy.js.erb. I'm calling it with remote: true from index.html.erb..

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) on ajaxComplete it seems as though it doesn't perform a function call on a given argument but instead calls a handler function when the Ajax requests complete.

> handler
>   Type: Function( Event event, jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject ajaxOptions )
>   The function to be invoked.

Your best bet would be to use an anonymous function to call `masonryUpdate`.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  masonryUpdate();
};
```

**Edit**

It might be better to cache your masonry spec in a variable.

```
var mas = $('#pins').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    isFitWidth: true
});
```

Then you can call masonry on that variable

```
var masonryUpdate = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    mas.masonry('reload');
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak, this works partially, but now all my divs are stacked on the left hand side on top of each other. For some reason it broke displaying them in two columns...?

Comment: @Suomi Oh, that's a little odd. I looked through your other question, are you sure you want to be calling masonry on `#pins` and not `#masonry-container`? If you are dealing with images you might need to look into imagesLoaded http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html I remember them breaking my masonry layout

Comment: @Suomi I'm wondering whether calling `.masonry();` with no arguments ignores the arguments you supplied at the beginning (specifically isFitWidth). Try the workround I posted above.